# How to cover java test using Coverage.py library

Tags: api, automation, sonarqube, coverage.py

Devlopment stack is in Python (flask) and our automation suite(API) is coded in Java .
So which is the best library can be used for code coverage

Answer (score 0):

If you have python tests, you can use coverage.py, it provides python code coverage that can be imported in SonarQube using SonarPython: [Python Coverage Results Import](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Python+Coverage+Results+Import).

If you have java tests, you can use JaCoCo, it provides java code coverage that can be imported in SonarQube using SonarJava: [Usage of JaCoCo with Java Plugin](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin).

If you have in the same project python+java code, coverage of both languages will be uploaded in SonarQube. But if you are looking for a coverage tool that support tests mixing java and python code, I mean initiating tests in one language and recording the coverage in both languages, this tool does not exist.

Comment: Automation tests are in Java (Rest-assured). It is a separate project which is being used to test the Python (Application) rest api's on Ci-Cd. I need coverage of the Python code only from the automation suite. Is it possible?

Comment: Did you try to run your python rest api through:
coverage run my_rest_api_web_server.py arg1 arg2 ...
Then you can run your java tests and have your java coverage.
Then you call a magic url that stop your python server, and you should be able to also have your python coverage.